# For While Loop Problems

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop, break

I am facing very strange behavior with a quite simple nested loop. Here is the code and when I use `count < 10` everything works like it should. BUT when I increase count above 10 I get an infinite loop and I don't where the error is. This is the code:

```
count = 0
while True:

    if count >= 10:
        break

    for tweet in c:
        tweets.append(tweet)
        print 'Upper Loop Date: ' + str(tweet.created_at) + "   " + str(count)
        count += 1
        if count >= 10:
            break

    for tweet in reversed(tweets):
        print 'Lower Loop Date: ' + str(tweet.created_at) + "   " + str(count)
```

And this is the result, the date decreases and then increases again, exactly the way I want it:

```
Upper Loop Date: 2017-02-01 23:59:55   0
Upper Loop Date: 2017-02-01 23:59:50   1
Upper Loop Date: 2017-02-01 23:59:50   2
Upper Loop Date: 2017-02-01 23:59:38   3
Upper Loop Date: 2017-02-01 23:59:35   4
Lower Loop Date: 2017-02-01 23:59:35   5
Lower Loop Date: 2017-02-01 23:59:38   5
Lower Loop Date: 2017-02-01 23:59:50   5
Lower Loop Date: 2017-02-01 23:59:50   5
Lower Loop Date: 2017-02-01 23:59:55   5
```

If I replace count with a figure higher than 10 I get an infinite loop.

Comment: if `c` doesn't contain enough `tweets`, this will run forever... your output makes perfect sense if c only contains 5 tweets

Comment: Puuh thanks, you saved my life!

Comment: or, saved my file?